# The most variant groups of periodic table

Tags: transition-metals, periodic-trends

Is it okay to call group 11 (formerly 1B) a "group"? I meant that according to my knowledge "A group is a horizontal column consisting of elements with similar valencies and a continuous gradation in physical and chemical properties" but there is no gradual trend or we don't obtain similar reactions for same circumstances. Members do not show similar oxidation states and do not form analogous compounds. Electronegativity values and other bonding characteristics also deviate badly from one another. Are they in a group just because their atomic numbers allot their positions in same vertical column? Shouldn't 1B and other d-block "groups" (which show such variant properties) treated as "ungrouped region" or something like that?

Comment: Placing in groups is directly related only to electronic configuration, "results may vary".

Comment: I assume you meant "vertical column"?

Answer (score 3):

Sure Group 11 is a group. And if you look in the right areas you see similarities between copper, silver and gold:

1)  Among the best electrical conductors even compared with other metals (http://eddy-current.com/conductivity-of-metals-sorted-by-resistivity/).

2)  Tend to prefer combining with "soft base" nonmetals:  Cu and Ag found as sulfides, gold is oxidized by $\ce{HNO_3}$ when a chloride source is added.

3)  Have some chemistry in the +1 oxidation state, especially wuth said soft-base nonmetals.

Comment: Conduction is somewhat physical quantity as I think and much more lanthanides tend to combine with soft base non-metals e.g iron. And iron and copper possess more similarity than copper and silver from this prospective.

Comment: Iron is found in nature primarily combined with oxygen (at least near the surface where it's chemically combined with anything at all).  It favors hard-base nonmetals much more than anything in Group 11.